# How do you save a Highcharter chart as a gif in R?

Tags: r, animation, highcharts, gif, r-highcharter

I work with financial data that is mostly non-continuous, meaning market closing times and weekends need to be omitted from graphs.

Highcharter seems good at handling such data but how do you convert its charts into gifs? I know how to do this with ggplot and gganimate, but that combination does not handle financial data well.

Below is a simple line chart (of 10-year Treasury yields) done in Highcharter but I'd like to animate it and save it as a gif. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#load packages -------

library(here)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)


# read in data -------

unemployment <- read_csv(here("data", "US 10-year Treasury.csv"))

# Line chart

data <- data.frame(unemployment)

hc <- data %>% hchart(
  'line', hcaes(x = Date, y = Yield),
  color = "steelblue"
) 

hc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not offered in the standard Highcharts library, therefore it has not been implemented in the Highcharter wrapper. Maybe R has some built-in tools for that gif export, unfortunately, I have no experience with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply — I’ve tried using Plotly too to resolve the issue of weekends and market opening/close times, but to no avail. For such a powerful platform, it’s strange R handles such financial data so poorly.